# TeamCity build agent on OS X. Problems with the command line build runner

Tags: xcode, macos, teamcity

I'm try to use the TeamCity build agent on OS X. One of my build steps involves moving the archive to a known location so I can grab it as a build artifact. The `xcodebuild archive` command puts .xcarchive files in %system.user.home%/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/*date/appName date time*.xcarchive. So I want to move and rename the .xcarchive files so that it's easier to grab the executable out of the bundle. FWIW, I also have a build step that clears out the Archives directory so I'll be sure that I only have one *date* folder with only one .xcarchive file within it. This command works fine from the command line:

```
$ /bin/mv /Users/buildagent/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/`date+%Y-%m-%d`/*.xcarchive /Users/buildagent/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/GetConnected.xcarchive
```

But using this for the build runner doesn't work (I just get mv's usage message):

```
/bin/mv %system.user.home%/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/`date +%%Y-%%m-%%d`/*.xcarchive %system.user.home%/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/GetConnected.xcarchive
```

What am I doing wrong? Are there some other characters that I need to escape? Is there any documentation about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, indeed you do need to escape those percents by doubling them. There is documentation for this on the TeamCity page [Defining and Using Build Parameters in Build Configuration](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration), but I'll admit that it's not easy to find. (Basically TeamCity uses the percent character for its own parameters).

The call that I used for this purpose was `` `date "+%%Y-%%m-%%d"` ``. Also, I needed to put quotes around the path (shell globbing was causing issues), so the whole command ends up being:

```
mv "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/`date "+%%Y-%%m-%%d"`/*.xcarchive" ./MyApp.xcarchive
```

Also, thanks for asking the question! I was trying to do just the same thing, and this headed me along the right path.